# Error when putting ??symbol in a cell with another expression

Tags: warning-messages

Putting `??symbol` in a cell and another expression in a different row of the cell returns the following error:

```
??symbol
1 + 2
```

> Information::ssym: symbol 1+2 is not a symbol or a valid string pattern. >>
>
> Information[symbol 1+2,LongForm->True]

But this does not happen with `?symbol`:

```
?symbol
1+2
```

> Global`symbol
>
> 3

Why does this happen?

Comment: Some parsing confusion on the FE? One can clearly see this since `??NDSolve` followed by `1+2` on new line gives `Information[NDsolve 1 + 2, LongForm -> True]` but this does not show up with the short form (default) version of `Information` which is `?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhat tautologically we can demonstrate that the Front End parses these differently:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute[UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]] 

parseString["?Sin\n2+2"]
parseString["??Sin\n2+2"]
```

> ```
> {BoxData[{RowBox[{"?", "Sin"}], RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}]}], StandardForm}
>
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"??", RowBox[{RowBox[{"Sin", "2"}], "+", "2"}]}]], StandardForm}
> ```

A question remains as to why.  Without any support I am going to suppose that the behavior of `??` is desired but that it was not extended to `?` because that operator is also used for [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html).